# Why can't show GUI screen with FuryBSD in VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, xorg, freebsd, gui

I downloaded FuryBSD 12.1 XFCE from [official site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/furybsd/files/12.1-2020Q2-XFCE/).

Launched it in VirtualBox.

From the official guide, [it](https://github.com/furybsd/furybsd-handbook/wiki/Installing-FuryBSD) should show a GUI desktop.

But in my machine it didn't. It showed terminal login screen.

[image]

I checked `/etc/rc.conf`

[image]

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

[image]

When I ran `startx` it got error. So I checked `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

[image]

Where is wrong? The VirtualBox is using 6.1 version.

Something can be [referred](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/virtualization-guest-virtualbox.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In virtualbox settings change your graphics controller to VboxSVGA and give it more video memory.